# Refresh table using AJAX in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to update table in MVC using ajax. I already inserted data in database using ajax.  I just want to update table after I insert a new row.

PS. i tried search but nothing helped me, i`m still confused.

```
Here is my code:

Main page View:

<div id="theTable">
    @Html.Partial("_IPTable") 
</div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Admin.js"></script>"`

Partial page View:

<table id="table">`
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Line</th>
        <th>Supplier</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.IPTable)`
    {
       <tr>
            <td>
                @item.ID
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Line
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Supplier
            </td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>enter code here

Controller view:

public ActionResult Admin()
        {
            // get data from database
            return View();
        }
public ActionResult _IPTable()
        {

            return PartialView();
        }
```

Ajax code for insert new record:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
//function will be called on button click having id btnsave
$("#btnSave").click(function () {
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
        url: "AdminInsert", // Controller/View
        data: { //Passing data
            //Reading text box values using Jquery
            Line: $("#txtLine").val(),
            Supplier: $("#txtSupplier").val()
        }
    });
});

}); </script>
```

Comment: Where is your code to insert a new row via ajax ?

Comment: The client side code i meant.

Comment: I posted it below.

Comment: post your $.ajax function code please, the jquery/javascrip code

Comment: Please post only the relevant part of ajax call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may create an action method which returns the HTML markup needed to render your table. Let's create a view model using which we will pass the table data.

```
public class ItemVm
{
  public string ItemId {set;get;}
  public string Line {set;get;}
  public string Supplier {set;get;}
}
```

Now in your action method, get your data from the table, load to a list of our view model class and send to the view. Since i am not sure about your table structure/ data access mecahnism. I am going to hard code the items. you may replace it with real data.

```
public ActionResult TableData()
{
  var items = new List<ItemVm>{
      new ItemVm { ItemId="A1", Line="L1", Supplier="S1" },
      new ItemVm { ItemId="A2", Line="L2", Supplier="S2" }    
  };
  return PartialView("TableData",items);
}
```

Now make sure that your partial view is strongly typed to a collection of our view model

```
@model List<ItemVm>
<table>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <tr><td>@item.ItemId</td><td>@item.Line</td></td>@item.Supplier</td></tr>
}
</table>
```

Now all you have to do is, call this action method and update the DOM with the response coming back. You can do that in the `success` event handler of your ajax call where you are inserting a new record. You may use the jQuery `load` method to update the relevant element in the DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#btnSave").click(function () {

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
        url: "AdminInsert", // Controller/View
        data: { //Passing data
            //Reading text box values using Jquery
            Line: $("#txtLine").val(),
            Supplier: $("#txtSupplier").val()
        }
    }).success(function() {
           $("#theTable").load("/YourControllerName/TableData");
       });
});
```

Now for the initial view, you may use our new partial view. But since it is expecting a list of `ItemVm`, you need to explicitly pass it instead of passing it via ViewBag.

Comment: awesome! Voila Daniel please ignore the use of  ViewBag while using $.ajax stuff.
you can use @model instead.

Comment: Thank You! PS It worked with TableData as a partial view.