# Refresh a section of a parent page when a child modal popup closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, popup

I am stuck at this issue, and have been ramming my head, it seems pretty viable and easy but it ain't clicking right now.

I have a `MVC6` view, which is composed of various `partials`.
On one of the partials, say I have an `anchor` tag:

```
@model ModelA
<div>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Id)
   <a onclick="BookProduct();" style="pointer:cursor">Book Product</a>
</div>
<div id="divModalBody" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div id="divModalPopup">
   </div>
</div>

<script>
   function BookProduct()
   {
      $.ajax({
         url:'Controller1/BookProduct',
         type:'GET',
         dataType:'html',
         data:SOME SAMPLE DATA,
         success:function(result)
           {
             if(result!=undefined)
               {
                 $("divModalBody").html(result);
               }
           },
         error:function(xhr)
           {
             console.log(xhr);
           }
        });
     }
</script>
```

This `BookProduct()` function basically calls a `controller` method and shows the result in a `modal popup` via an `AJAX call`.

I perform some operations in that `popup` and click on `Save`.

The data is validated and saved into the DB, the control comes back to the `success part of the modal popup`.

```
I then close the popup and need to refresh the partial of the parent page and maybe bind it to a list.
```

How do I make my parent page understand that the `popup` work has been completed and now the `partial view` needs to be refreshed?

Please guide.

Comment: Can you share the success part of your popup call ? You should be able to access the DOM there and reload the partial view using ajax.

Comment: @Shyju..apparently above is just a sample code, the popup and its code has been developed by a fellow developer and it lies in a separate js file, frankly speaking I don't know hat has been written on the success part of the popup. I am not sure if I can access my DOM over there. But if you give some pointers on how to perform it, I'll try it tomorrow, because I don't have access to TFS now. Thanks

Comment: You should be able to access the DOM as the poup will be usually appended to the same page.

Comment: @Shyju..Well I'll try tomorrow..so in the success part of the popup, I will have to reload the div containing the partial view? I am not very sure about it coz the model accepted by my partial view and the return type in the success part of the popup maybe different...Any pointers?

Comment: make an ajax call to get the partial view content, you may use jQuery load method to do so. Take a look at [Refresh table using AJAX in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635966/refresh-table-using-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @Shyju: I see..let me try it tomorrow and I shall keep you posted..Any relevant links you might have for this just for reference?

Comment: I posted one in my previous comment.

Comment: @Shyju..Thanks for it. I will try this tomorrow and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

From your controller you must use return partialview rather than
return jsonresult.